proof of sum of infinite series for epsilon
Real Analysis by Royden has used in multiple proofs the below infinite expansion of episilon.
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon}{2^k} = \epsilon$
where $\epsilon > 0$
my question is what is the proof of this sum because according to my understanding
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon}{2^k} < \epsilon$, and there is no mention of limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\epsilon}{2^k} = \epsilon$ which can introduce the equality.

$\epsilon$ has nothing to do with it; you could divide it out since it's nonzero and you're really looking at the geometric series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1/2}{1-1/2} = 1$.

Well your intuition (which is faulty and shouldn't be relied on but... should be listened to and evaluted) ougth to tell you that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac \epsilon{2^k}= \epsilon \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^k} = \epsilon (1 + \frac 12 + \frac 14 + .....)=\epsilon \cdot 1 = \epsilon$.

"because according to my understanding ∑∞k=1ϵ2k<ϵ,"  Why would you think that?  Is $\lim_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^k} < 1$?

The DEFINITION of a $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n$ is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ (if it exists).  So if $a_k >0$ (but $a_k\to 0$) the you will have $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k < \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m a_k$ for all $n$ but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k =\lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m a_k$.  So $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac \epsilon{2^k} < \epsilon$ for all $n$ but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac \epsilon{2^k} = \lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^m \frac \epsilon{2^k} = \epsilon$.  Exactly.

$\epsilon$ is just a constant.
If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k$ converges to $M$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c\cdot b_m= c\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k = c \cdot M$.
And $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^k} = 1$.
So $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac \epsilon{2^k} = \epsilon\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{2^k}= \epsilon \cdot 1 = \epsilon$.
=======
So it turns out the difficulty lay with not knowing that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ were defined to be the exact same thing.
I am of the school that meaning of an infinite sum can be defined to what we need it to be and we need it to be $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.  But there are those of the school that an infinite sum has an intrinsic meaning one its own.
Suppose so.  If so is there a reason to assume that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = L$ that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k=L$?
For the sake of simplicity we can show that if $a_k \ge 0$ that this must be the case.
Suppose $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = m \ne L = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.
Then $|L-m| > 0$ and there is an $N$ so that if $n > N$ the $|L - \sum_{k=1}^na_k| < |L - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k|$.
As $a_k \ge 0$ we know $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$.  If we assume $L > m$ we get
$L - \sum_{k=1}^n a_k < L -\sum_{k=1}^{infty} a^k$ which implies the contradiction: $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k > \sum_{k=1}^{infty} a^k$.
So we must assume $L < m$.  But as $a_k \ge 0$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is increasing and so there must be an $N$ where $n > N$ would imply $L < \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$.  This would be a direct contradiction that $L$ was the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$.
So we must conclude that if an infinite sum has a meaning then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.
I think we can show that is true if if $a_k$ are not strictly non-negative but... it might involve some messiness with absolute values of difference.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
